# How to show that the following series converges to 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}$, non-zero only on $[0,2)$. In particular $f(x)=1,x\in[0,1]$ and decreasing to zero, starting from $x=1$. Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(2x)$. Show that $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty g\left(\frac{x}{2^j}\right)=1,\quad \forall x\geq 1$$

I can show this for some fixed $x\geq 1$, but have no idea, how to show it for all $x\geq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** You have a **telescoping sum** here, you may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^N g\left(\frac{x}{2^j}\right)&=\sum_{j=0}^N \left(f\left(\frac{x}{2^j}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{2^{j-1}}\right)\right)\\\\
&=f\left(\frac{x}{2^N}\right)-f(2x)
\end{align}
$$ and may conclude.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^ng\left(\frac x{2^j}\right)&=f(x)-f(2x)+f\left(\frac x2\right)-f(x)+\cdots+f\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)-f\left(\frac x{2^{n-1}}\right)\\
&=-f(2x)+f\left(\frac x{2^n}\right)\to1
\end{align}$$
since $f(2x)=0$ and $x/2^n$ is eventually in $[0,1]$ (namely, for $n>\log_2 x$). In fact, only finitely many terms of the series are not $0$.